# How to position a relative element in the same coordinates as his parent in the document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating and element in JavaScript to append it as a child of
another `div`:

```
var a = document.querySelector(".a");

var b = document.createElement("div");
b.style.position = "relative";
b.style.height = a.offsetHeight+"px";
b.style.width = a.offsetWidth+"px";
b.style.background = "blue";
b.style.top="0px";
a.appendChild(b);
```

But I want to position the "b" element completely  over the "a" element.

I know that I should do something like that to achieve the effect:

```
b.style.top = -b.offsetTop+"px";
```

But there is no way I can find the `offsetTop` that will be taken by "b" since it has no been added to the document yet.

This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/a36eLwu3/

How can I position a relative element in the same coordinates 
of his parent in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element *has* to be relatively positioned, you could set a negative `top` value equal to the height of the parent element:

```
b.style.top = -Math.abs(a.offsetHeight) + 'px';
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d06Lcv7j/)

```
var a = document.querySelector(".a");

var b = document.createElement("div");
b.style.position = "relative";
b.style.height = a.offsetHeight+"px";
b.style.width = a.offsetWidth+"px";
b.style.background = "blue";
b.style.top = -Math.abs(a.offsetHeight) + 'px';
a.appendChild(b);
```

---

If you can absolutely position the element, it would be easier to absolutely position it *relative* to the parent. Then give position it to cover the parent using `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`. In doing so, it will be the same size with the same coordinates of the parent.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5kng8x/)

```
.a {
    background:red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.a > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

This would be a safer, more reliable approach compared to the first JS option.

Comment: I was going to suggest to him that he set b.style.top = "-" + a.offsetHeight + "px"; but I like the use of -Math.abs().

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I know of to place two objects directly on top of one another is to put them both in the same container, make the container be `position: relative` and then make both objects (which are siblings in this structure) be `position: absolute` with the same `top` and `left`.  You can do all of this without any calculation and can specify everything via CSS.

Structurally, it looks like this:

```
Container (position: relative; height: xxx; width: yyy;)
    Child A (position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;)
    Child B (position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;)
```

I have used this structure for a slideshow where I'm cross fading (fading out one image and fading in the other image).